# How to call web service for cross platform with reusable single share code lib

Tags: c#, android, ios, visual-studio

Now I am going on with the web service call for cross platform with the visual studio of xamarin.forms have build a sample **hello world** program with the portable lib.

Now I need to build it for web service should use a reusable single code share between various platform.

Tried with the below:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/19303/how-to-consume-wcf-service-in-xamarin-forms-pcl

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/XamarinFormsWriteOnceRunEverywhereANDBeNative.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/890595/introduction-to-xamarin-android-with-mvvmcross/

I face lot of issues.

Comment: What type of Web Service is it?  RESTful? SOAP?

Comment: actually i am new this can you please guide me through the step by step tutorials

Comment: i need to build it for cross platform should use single code reusable using pcl

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a RESTful web service, you should be able to do everything you need with an HttpClient.  Try this thread:

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11846/httpclient-in-ios-android-and-wp8-with-a-portable-class-library